# HTML attributes : What are the interesting things that can be done using them?

Tags: html

What are the interesting things that can be done using HTML attributes?

(apart from their original intended purpose, duh)

Comment: I don't think there are things you can do with attributes than assigning them to tags to give them attributes. I really don't get the point of your question.

Comment: Not true at all, for example placeholders on inputs, and the ping attribute on anchors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this page, has a lot of informative new specified attributes, namely on ANCHORS and VIDEO/AUDIO, also form elements

http://simon.html5.org/html-elements

Answer (score 1):

Interesting things? Well, I guess they can be used for controversial political commentary:

```
<div id="countries">
  <div id="united_states" class="totally_broke">United States</div>
  <div id="china" class="winning">China</div>
</div>
```